# How to search unique array key?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the key of an array based on the value.

```
$array1=array(
'0'=>'test1',
'1'=>'test2',
'2'=>'test3',
'3'=>'test1'
)

$array2=array(
'0'=>'11',
'1'=>'22',
'2'=>'33',
'3'=>'44'
)
```

I have

`$source` is the needle. it could be '`test1`', '`test2`' or '`test3`'

```
for loop to get different $source string

   if(in_array($source[$i], $array1)){
      $id=array_search($source[$i],$array1);
      //I want to output 11, 22 or 33 based on $source
      //However, my $array1 has duplicated value.
      //In my case, if $source is test1, the output will be 11,11 instead of 11 and 44

      echo $array2[$id]);
   }
```

I am not sure how to fix this. My brain is fried. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

i.e. `$keys = array_keys( $myArray, $theValue );` and to get just the first: `$keys[0];`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$array3 = array_flip(array_reverse($array1, true));
$needle = $source[$i];
$key = $array3[$needle];
echo $array2[$key];
```

What `array_flip` does is exchange the keys and values. In case of duplicate values, only the last pair will be exchanged. To counter this, we use `array_reverse` but we preserve the key structure.

Edit : For more clarification, here's a dry run.

```
$array1=array(
'0'=>'test1',
'1'=>'test2',
'2'=>'test3',
'3'=>'test1'
)
```

After `array_reverse($array1, true)` the output will be

```
array(
'3' => 'test1',
'2' => 'test3',
'1' => 'test2',
'0' => 'test1'
)
```

Now, when we flip this, the output will be

```
array(
'test1' => '0', //would be 3 initially, then overwritten by 0
'test2' => '1',
'test3' => '2',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip! But after reading the manual of array_flip() I would says array_flip is not a good idea for most applications as only strings or numbers are allowed as values. However in **this** case it will work

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the values themselves, are `Strings`. It will not work on array of `Objects`, or `Arrays` for that matter.